# CREATE VIEW equivalent in new Room persistence library

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a RecyclerView of Top 10 users in my app. I populate it with a cursor that reads from a SQL VIEW in sql that aggregates from different tables that are related by foreign keys. I'd like to re write the SQLite boiler plate to use the new Room library. However, I do not know how a SQL VIEW is to be implemented in Room. DAO seems to be only for entities(tables), or perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: I've removed the promise of question updates, since it is our experience that questions will often have those messages left in for the long term. In general it is best to hold off posting a question until you have everything you need to show the reader.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, I thought I could get a jump on the question and then finish it today, but in the future I will hold off til everything is ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use POJOs that join multiple tables from a DAO. From the [Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#daos-query-multiple-tables):

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
   @Query("SELECT user.name AS userName, pet.name AS petName "
          + "FROM user, pet "
          + "WHERE user.id = pet.user_id")
   public LiveData<List<UserPet>> loadUserAndPetNames();

   // You can also define this class in a separate file, as long as 
   // you add the "public" access modifier.
   static class UserPet {
       public String userName;
       public String petName;
   }
}
```

This also works fine with the aggregation functions.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with `2.1.0-alpha01` version of Room library, you can define `@DatabaseView`s that internally make use SQLite of `VIEW`.

From `2.1.0-alpha02` you can even use them for fields annotated with `@Relation`.

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT user.id, user.name, user.departmentId," +
        "department.name AS departmentName FROM user " +
        "INNER JOIN department ON user.departmentId = department.id")
data class UserDetail(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String?,
    val departmentId: Long,
    val departmentName: String?
)
```

Example extracted from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views